# Get partition column for a table in Greenplum

Tags: partitioning, greenplum

How can I find what the partitioning scheme is for a table? Is it in information_schema or in the pg_class related tables?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing me in the right direction,  [pg_partition_columns](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/ref_guide/system_catalogs/pg_partition_columns.html) is the table I need.